# Draw dots on the coordinate plane

Tags: graphics

I draw the coordinate plane using this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin,->] (-3.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=west] {x};
\draw[thin,->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south] {y};
\foreach \x in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
\draw (\x cm,2pt) -- (\x cm,-2pt);
\foreach \y in {-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}
\draw (2pt, \y cm) -- (-2pt, \y cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Now I want to draw several black dots on points (0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(1,1). How can I do that? Also I hope I can change the radius of the dots.

Comment: `\fill (0,0) circle (1.5pt);` where `1.5pt` is the radius.

Comment: `\draw plot[mark=*, only marks] coordinates {(0,0) (0,2) (2,0)};` would be my preferred method.

Comment: Change the radius of all the dots? Or just one?

Comment: Have a look at the `pgfplots` package; whatever it is that you're trying to do is likely covered by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution with regular Tikz. If you want to change the size of the dots, it might be done. But the "how" might differ depending on how you want them to change.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thin,->] (-3.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[thin,->] (0,-3.5) -- (0,4.5) node[above] {$y$};

\foreach \x [count=\xi starting from 0] in {-3,-2,-1,,1,2,3,4}{% ticks
    \draw (\x,2pt) -- (\x,-2pt);
    \draw (2pt,\x) -- (-2pt,\x);
    \ifodd\xi
        \node[anchor=north] at (\x,0) {$\x$};
        \node[anchor=east] at (0,\x) {$\x$};
    \fi
}

\foreach \point in {(0,0),(0,2),(2,0),(1,1)}{% points
    \fill \point circle (2pt);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-3.5,xmax=4.5,ymin=-3.5,ymax=4.5,
    ]
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {(0,0) (0,2) (2,0) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]